# The target "Package" does not exist in the project - Web deploy installed

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy

I have a build server build on Teamcity.

I'm trying to build a package using it, but I get an error.

> The target "Package" does not exist in the project

I googled about this issue and found out I need to install Web Deploy. So I did. I've installed Web Deploy 3.5, but the error is still present. I've even did a reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was top result on DuckDuckGo for me, so I feel this is an appropriate place to share [Troy Hunt's wisdom](https://www.troyhunt.com/why-target-package-does-not-exist-in/). My "ProjectFile" was a Solution file. Solution files do not support the "Package" Target directly. My Build scripts (written in [Cake](https://cakebuild.net) in this case) were attempting to package the solution instead of the applicable projects.